# Irreducible polynomial cannot have only perfect power values

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Does there exist a non-constant irreducible monic polynomial $P(x)$ with integer coefficients such that for every integer $n$ there are integers $a,b \geq 2$ such that $P(n) = a^b$?

No idea how to approach this - apart from a hint that considering the derivative could be useful - maybe with $P(x)Q(x) + P'(x)R(x) =$ const?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224881/polynomials-which-always-assume-perfect-power-values

Comment: "Irreducible" should be in the body of the question, not just in the title.